# SQL - Java/Eclipse - UPDATE statement query [Re-asked, to insert more code]

Tags: mysql, eclipse

So what i want to do is "Update the 'usertype' column in the 'user' table WHERE the email(/user) value is obtained from the textbox " below is my database connection code (which 100% works)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Database_link  {
    Connection connect = null;
    Statement state = null;
    public static Connection dbConnector()
    {
        try{
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file: // my DB path  )

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Successful");
            return connect;

            }
        catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed Connection");
                return null;
            }
        }

}
```

> Below is the sql statement code with the error "The operator & is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String"

```
 JButton GrantButton = new JButton("Grant Seller Access");
            GrantButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    try {

    String update_query = "UPDATE user SET usertype = 'seller' WHERE email = " & GrantField.getText()";"
                            //Here is where the error is stated on eclipse

                PreparedStatement pSt = connect.prepareStatement(update_query);
                        pSt.setString(1, GrantField.getText());

                        pSt.execute();

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "The Request has been approved");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            });
```

> Sorry to have repeated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String update_query = "UPDATE user SET usertype = 'seller' WHERE email = " & GrantField.getText()";"
```

should be like

```
    String update_query = "UPDATE user SET usertype = 'seller' WHERE email = ?"
```

Comment: but don't forget to clean up resources. pSt should be closed in finally clause, or, if you are using java 1.7 and newest, you should do: 
`                try(PreparedStatement pSt = connect.prepareStatement(update_query)) {`

and i believe you should call pSt.executeUpdate() instead.

Comment: The new String works, thank you very much, and i'll sort the cleaning up as well :)

Answer (score 0):

String update_query = "UPDATE user SET usertype = 'seller' WHERE email = " & GrantField.getText()";"

Wrong syntax. That's why this error comes.

"The operator & is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String"

Correct syntax is -

String update_query = "UPDATE user SET usertype = 'seller' WHERE email = "+GrantField.getText();

But you have to use ? because it will get value from below line.

pSt.setString(1, GrantField.getText());

We use '+' operator for concatenate instead of & (ampersand) operator.